# Install major windows update after going back to a previous build

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1511

After installing the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, I experienced some issues which caused me to use the built in option to go back to the previous build (1511). How can I now reinstall the update that I previously rolled back?

Comment: ... and stop Windows from re-installing it! I've got two systems now where the installation of 1607 fails with no information on why. It then restores the previous 1511 version and starts all over again. One of the systems has broken out of this loop when the update destroyed the Windows installation altogether. The `C:` drive is still there, but I cannot boot it and I cannot install over it because it reckons it's in the middle of an update. To say I'm unimpressed is a considerable understatement. I very much hope you get an answer.

Comment: Just checking, is this a boot loop situation where you never get windows to fully load, or it loads, and shortly after you are put into an "updating" screen?  1) have you tried repeated hitting F8 (fastboot makes catching it difficult at best)  2) do you have boot media for windows 10? can you make a bootable USB dongle via another windows machine?

Comment: @TG2 My issue isn't a boot loop, I literally am not sure how to initiate the update procedure to v1607. It updated perfectly, and rolled back perfectly, but I am currently unable to repeat the update. I could reinstall windows, but that would be a last resort really. But yes, I can make a bootable USB dongle. (Maybe you were addressing AFH tho, that does sound like a boot loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the update "again" after a roll back.  I don't know if microsoft puts you on a "update after" list or re-que for download, but if you don't want to wait, use the manual updater found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history